# how do I correct the error: pathspec message when committing in git?

Tags: git

I am trying to commit changes with the command `git commit "commit message"` to a local branch, but am getting the following message:

```
error: pathspec 'commit message' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: This can also happen, if you forgot to add some new files. So, first the files needs to be added with `git add ...`

Comment: Alternatively, while using Vscode double quotes didn't work for me, it was single quotes.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's `git commit -m "commit message"`.  You're missing the `-m` flag.

Comment: Thanks. I have been looking for this solution on the whole Internet because I was doing `git commit --amend 'commit message'` instead of `git commit --amend -m 'commit message'`. I had found solutions involving double quotes, but which were totally unrelated to my problem.

Answer (score 35):

If you're using Windows you need to use double quotes

Comment: Thank you, it took some time to recognize the qoutes-issue after background in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Very Good point using double quotes on windows.  It cost me hours trying to figure out why the single quote didn't work.  Thank you!  One thing I want to mention here from my own experience is it seems you still have to do 'git commit -a' for some reason to be able later on to push to the remote git repo such as 'git push'.  and it's almost no point doing just 'git commit -m "commit message..."' coz you will type it up in a vi editor again anyway when you do 'git commit -a' on windows.  I think only on windows you need to do 'git commit -a' instead of just 'git commmit -m "msg"'