# git commit -m "some message" returns error: pathspec

Tags: git, git-commit

I'm trying to push a commit to my repository with a command-line commit message:

```
git commit -m "some commit message"
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'message' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I've seen this question answered for obvious cases, like forgetting to use the '-m' flag when pushing a commit ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133138/how-do-i-correct-the-error-pathspec-message-when-committing-in-git)), but I'm using the correct flag -- this exact syntax works on other machines with clones of the same repository. On the troublesome (Red Hat 4.1.2) machine, I'm using:

```
git version 1.7.3.3
```

And I get the same error if I try using the long-form flag:

```
git commit --message="some commit message"
```

Has anyone seen this before? I don't have root access on this machine, so I can't update, but I'm wondering if this is a known issue with the above version (didn't find anything from googling though), or possibly a problem with the git configuration on this system?

**Edit: Solved!**

I think I found the problem. I'm not too familiar with Red Hat, but what I found is the executable */usr/local/bin/git* points to some executable called *run-rhel*, e.g.

```
/usr/local/bin/git -> run-rhel
```

and this executable is messing with git's command structure. I prepended the real git executable to my $PATH:

```
export PATH=/path/to/real/executable:$PATH
```

and now everything seems to work! Thanks for the quick response though!

Comment: Ouch; that sounds bad actually. Perhaps you should ask about this behaviour on a Red Hat mailing list? In a worst case, it's worth a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your shell is messing around with the double quote. From the error message, I think git sees this command:

```
git commit -m some commit message
```

So it interprets 'commit' (the second use of the word) and 'message' as path specifications, and 'some' as the commit message.

It would be good to try and see if other (non-git) commands that require quoting also have this problem. E.g., does the following show all files in the directory, or an error message:

```
ls "*"
```

Comment: Ah, good idea. **ls "*"** returns: **ls: *: No such file or directory**, which I think is expected? Just to make sure it wasn't my fault, I mv'd my bash_profile elsewhere and re-logged in, but I get the same error with the bash system defaults. I checked /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc but I don't see anything suspicious...strange!